# can not open input file ws2_32.libkernel32.lib

Tags: c++, linker, winsock2

I started taking [tenouk's](http://www.tenouk.com/)tutorials for socket programming in windows environment. I currently have both the client and server code working but **only** in debug mode. When I try to build the code under release mode I get a linker error LNK1181. Now before you say that there are a lot of threads to check for this error let me just say that I have added the correct dependencies on the project. I get the can not open input file ws2_32.lib error. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 RC. Is it safe to assume that there is a bug? I had a conversation with a guy and he told me that I should be able to change the project preferences and accept .dll files instead of .lib when building the project. I wasn't able to figure out how to do this yet. Is this possible? The most probable thing is that I'm missing something but since I'm not familiar with VS I wanted someone to show me the right direction.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot get the linker to accept DLL files.  There's a ws2_32.lib and there's a kernel32.lib.  There is no .lib file that's named "ws2_32.libkernel32.lib".  That was probably a mistake when you set the linker's Additional Dependencies setting, forgetting to use the ; semicolon to separate the names.

Comment: Thanks so much Hans. It's always the semicolons